# Allow only Postfix to send mails through port 25 - iptables rule confusion

Tags: iptables, postfix, firewall, smtp, email-server

I know there is already a thread, mentioning how to allow only postfix to send mails through via port 25.
[Firewall rule to only allow Postfix to send email through SMTP on port 25](https://serverfault.com/questions/740216/firewall-rule-to-only-allow-postfix-to-send-email-through-smtp-on-port-25)

My problem is, that if I specify the iptables rule mentioned in the linked thread I cannot send emails anymore.

> `iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner ! --uid-owner postfix -m tcp -p tcp
>   --dport 25 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-admin-prohibited`
>
> `ip6tables -I OUTPUT -m owner ! --uid-owner postfix -m tcp -p tcp --dport 25 -j
>   REJECT --reject-with icmp6-adm-prohibited`

If I however specify `root` for `--uid-owner` it works again.
So I looked up under which user postfix is running via `ps aux | grep postfix`:

```
postfix   8508  0.0  0.0  67476  4524 ?        S    13:35   0:00 pickup -l -t fifo -u -c
postfix  13069  0.0  0.0  67472  4404 ?        S    14:47   0:00 anvil -l -t unix -u -c
postfix  13266  0.0  0.0 105164 10444 ?        S    14:55   0:00 smtpd -n smtp -t inet -u -c -o stress= -s 2
postfix  13267  0.0  0.0  67476  4452 ?        S    14:55   0:00 proxymap -t unix -u
postfix  13274  0.0  0.0  35584  4200 ?        S    14:55   0:00 plesk_saslauthd -l -t unix -u -c status=5 listen=6 dbpath=/plesk/passwd.db
root     13335  0.0  0.0  16976   988 pts/0    S+   14:55   0:00 grep --color=auto postfix
root     14608  0.0  0.0  65408  4564 ?        Ss   Apr19   0:17 /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/master
postfix  25855  0.0  0.0  67648  4640 ?        S    10:17   0:01 qmgr -l -t fifo -u
postfix  25908  0.0  0.0  80836  6772 ?        S    10:18   0:00 tlsmgr -l -t unix -u -c
postfix  26156  0.0  0.0 398972  3484 ?        Ssl  Apr18   0:05 /usr/lib/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote -p inet:12768@127.0.0.1 -t 7210   -P /run/psa-pc-remote.pid -u postfix -g popuser -n
```

I know that postfix has a master process, which needs to be run as `root` because otherwise binding on port 25 would not be possible. However, I thought that postfix does spawn subprocesses under user `postfix` to actually deliver emails (via smtp).
Any ideas why the iptables rule does not work? Does the user `postfix` not send emails (are they delivered instead via user `root`)? What am I missing here?

EDIT: postfix config - **main.cf**

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = zeus.lotsearch.de
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost.lotsearch.de, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = , 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
tls_medium_cipherlist = HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
message_size_limit = 0
```

**master.cf**

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman unix - n n - - pipe flags=R user=list:list argv=/usr/lib/plesk-9.0/postfix-mailman ${nexthop} ${user} ${recipient}


plesk_virtual unix - n n - - pipe flags=DORhu user=popuser:popuser argv=/usr/lib/plesk-9.0/postfix-local -f ${sender} -d ${recipient} -p /var/qmail/mailnames
pickup fifo n - - 60 1 pickup
qmgr fifo n - n 1 1 qmgr
smtps inet n - - - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes

plesk_saslauthd unix y y y - 1 plesk_saslauthd status=5 listen=6 dbpath=/plesk/passwd.db

plesk-94.130.34.42-2a01-4f8-10b-1f55--2 unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=94.130.34.42 -o smtp_bind_address6=2a01:4f8:10b:1f55::2 -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

plesk-94.130.34.42- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=94.130.34.42 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

submission inet n - - - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
```

Comment: Ok I added the configuration files main.cf + master.cf. Do I need to add further configs? In which file is defined, under which user postfix runs?

Answer (score 2):

The rules:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner postfix -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner root -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

allows only postfix and root users to send emails. If someone has root access, the game is over. And we don't run services as root, right?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course I do not run services as root. But the postfix master process has to be run as root (otherwise port binding on port 25 will not work). I know if someone (evil) has root access nothing can help because he can possibly overwrite every configuration I made...

Comment: it starts as root, but drops to postfix user after binding on required ports (etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be delivering outgoing mail through an smtp client that runs with `unpriv=n`, which is postfix master.cf language for **that service runs as root**.
The configs you posted do not prove that - but my guess is thats what your transport map is configured to use.

```
name      type   private  unpriv chroot wakeup  maxproc command
plesk-..  unix   -        n      n      -       -       smtp -o ..
```

What you need to do: carefully examine who and why added that line (the name *plesk* looks like a hint), which part of the service actually needs root privileges and then seperate those tasks from the smtp client.
Rule of thumb: *Delivering mails is generally not a task that requires many special privileges. Running an smtp client as root is usually insane.*

It is possible that root privileges for your smtp client are entirely unnesessary and you can just change the service from `unpriv=n` to `unpriv=y`.

**I highly recommend that after getting rid of Plesk, you start from a fresh set of configurations from your favourite distro and only add the modifications you need.** Plesk is notorious for making configurations changes that are far from easily secured&maintained outside the scope of plesk, if possible at all you should write your own, not copying the plesk ones.

Comment: Thank you. I questioned PLESK about that (mis-)configuration and they stated, that this is the master process which needs to run as root (because of port-bindings at port 25). Is the line you posted in your answer related to postfix master-process or to the spawning of the sub-processes?
I did already setup multiple domains using PLESK, so removing PLESK is difficult in my case...

Comment: Thats not the only reason - pipe/local/virtual services might need root too, e.g. to setuid to call some LDA. Yet the port binding is just a non-argument in the case of smtp CLIENTS, because smtp clients do not bind to privileged ports.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you need an INPUT rule for your mail traffic.  This also works for GitLab's postfix.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sport 25,110,143 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

You may need other outgoing rules, but i found that the mail servers seem to ping back to the server when sending out on port 25.

You dont have to use the multiport, its just there for an example. If you wanted only 25 on that rule it would look like this:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`